# How can I add an image to the bottom of my page while ignoring the bottom margin?

Tags: graphics, floats

I would like to add an image to the title page of my document. Since it is the cover page, it does not really need to adhere to the margins and I would like my image to span the width of the page and also not have whitespace below it due to the bottom margin.

The latter has been achieved but I cannot seem to get rid of the whitespace, as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

This is how I setup my image as of now:

```
\begin{figure}[!b]
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.5\textwidth]{Images/Bottles.jpg}}
\end{figure}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please show a Minimal Working Example, as some advice could depend on the way you setup your document, which packages you're using, and so on.

Comment: Don't use float. Insert this image in `tikz` node which is positioned at bottom of page.

Comment: Use some way to position your picture directly at given coordinates, such as Ti*k*Z or `\AddToShipoutPicture` (from the `eso-pic` package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment: Don't use float. Insert this image in tikz node which is positioned at bottom of page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
remember picture, overlay,
                        ]
\node[inner sep=0pt, above] at (current page.south) 
        {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=33mm] {example-image}}; % sett height size as you like to have
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For final position of image you need to compile above MWE at least twice.

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, this works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without additional packages. It uses the `shipout/background` hook.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\bgimage{}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\bgimage}
\AddToHook{env/titlepage/begin}{%
    \def\bgimage{%
        \put (0pt,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.2\paperheight]{example-image}}
    }%
}
\AddToHook{env/titlepage/after}{\def\bgimage{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\Huge Titlepage
\end{titlepage}

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]